# How do I integrate the inequality $ \frac{f(\frac{1}{2}+h)+f(\frac{1}{2}-h)}{2} \leqslant f(\frac{1}{2})$ over the range $h\in[0,1/2]$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, inequality, convex-analysis

I would like to know the formal steps and theory. I was told that, by integrating this inequality, I can achieve one of the definitions of a concave function in the interval [0,1].

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by integrating an inequality?

Comment: @dustin, okay, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @ki3i not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Note that by substituting $h\mapsto\frac12-h$
$$
\int_0^{1/2}f\left(\frac12-h\right)\,\mathrm{d}h=\int_0^{1/2}f(h)\,\mathrm{d}h
$$
and by substituting $h\mapsto h-\frac12$
$$
\int_0^{1/2}f\left(\frac12+h\right)\,\mathrm{d}h=\int_{1/2}^1f(h)\,\mathrm{d}h
$$
Add these and divide by $2$.

Comment: I am assuming you know how to integrate
$$
\int_0^{1/2}f\left(\frac12\right)\,\mathrm{d}h
$$